# How to import or install pre-built python extension module (C++) (i.e. library not compiled via setuptools)?

Tags: python, c++, setuptools, pybind11, extension-modules

I have a C++ project for which I am developing a Python interface. For now I am using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) since it seems pretty neat, and has some nice tools for building the extension module with CMake, which is how the main C++ project is built.

Via CMake I managed to get a shared library containing the interface functions to build, however now that I have it I don't know how to tell Python that it exists and make it import-able. I don't want to reconfigure the whole build of the project to be launched via Python (i.e. as described [here](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example) with setuptools) because it is a big project and I am just providing a Python interface to part of it. So it would be preferable if I could just build the shared library for Python along with the rest of the C++ code, and then just later on run "setup.py install" to do whatever else needs to be done to make the shared library visible to Python.

Is this possible? Or do I need to do some other sort of refactoring, like make the main project build some other pure C++ libraries, which I then just link into the Python extension module library which is built separately via setuptools?

Comment: Is this binary module standalone or a part of some Python package that includes pure Python modules as well?

Comment: It's standalone, well at least for now it is. Let's assume that it is :). I have made some progress with my refactoring option which I suppose is more flexible, but I'd still like to know if the first method is possible.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to install just one binary module you can create an simple installer just for that module. Let's assume that you have a binary module `foo.so` (or `foo.pyd` if you are working on Windows) that is already built with your cmake-generated build script. Then you can create a simple setup setup script:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.1.2.3',
    py_modules=['foo']
)
```

Then you need to add `MANIFEST.in` file to pick your binary module file:

```
include foo.so
```

So you need 3 files:

```
foo.so
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
```

Now you can do `python setup.py install` from your Python virtual environment, and your binary module will be installed in it. If you want to distribute your module, then it's better to install Python `wheel` package and create a `.whl` file: `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. Such "wheel" can later be installed with `pip` command. Note that binary modules must be installed on the same platform and Python version that was used to build those modules.